# About the subdifferential of a convex function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, differential, subgradient

Suppose $f$ is a convex function over $\mathbb R$, and there exists two points $b_1 < b_2$, $a_1 \leq 0\leq a_2$ such that

$$a_1 \in \partial f(b_1), $$
$$ a_2 \in \partial f(b_2).$$
Then $\arg\min f(x) \in [b_1,b_2].$

Im actually asking this to understand the proof in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1427055/maximum-of-sum-of-strictly-concave-functions). The proof is immediate if we assume $f$ differentiable, but i dont know really how to work with subdifferentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that
$$f(x) \ge a_1(x-b_1)+f(b_1)$$
$$f(x) \ge a_2(x-b_2)+f(b_2)$$
for all $x$.

In particular, the first inequality implies $f(x) \ge f(b_1)$ if $x < b_1$, and the second inequality implies $f(x) \ge f(b_2)$ if $x > b_2$. So the minimizer must be in $[b_1, b_2]$.

Comment: Nice proof only using the definition. Thanks!